# What the login flow of Spring Security

Tags: authentication, spring-security

I am using Sping MVC and Spring Security but have some confusions in my mind. With Spring Security, the action of login form is '{application context}/j_spring_security_check', which hides the whole process of authentication. In Spring MVC, I can easily find out the corresponding controller to a specific url. Apparently, there's no controller to handle j_spring_security_check. I know that the authentication happens in spring security context. But how does it happen and the what is the whole process when login form is submitted to j_spring_security_check? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

its configured in UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter which extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter. It contains method  requiresAuthentication which checks if configured login path ( j_spring_security_check in this case ) exists in url.

You can check it in IDE or http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/3.0.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java